# TabControl Reversed words vb.net right to left

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, themes

I'm using theme called Net Seal
my problem is when I make the tapcontrol right to left , the words got reversed .
like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/2utGe.png

the theme code that I'm using is located in pastebin.com/0tQ2eqYV
sorry I can't post all the code

I need to write the title of tapcontrol in arabic 
how can I fix this problem

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue if any one has it
the solution is
from the properties of tapcontrole just changing the Alignment to (Right) and RightToLeftLayout to (False) and RightToLeft to (Yes)